# App crash after taken 260 photos on iPad mini 2 or 560 photos on iPad air 2 - UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

After `iOS 10` released, we are getting support emails from our users where the app crashes after the user takes certain number of photos.

We managed to replicated issue using the source code below, it looks like `iOS 10` issue. (`UIImagePickerController`)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3yGkt2WatFKd0p3bndEUkdBd00

> on **iPad Mini2 (iOS 10)**, it crashes around **267** photos taken. 
>   on **iPad Air2(iOS 10)**, it crashes around **560**.

It should be able to take unlimited photos.

Anybody have any workaround to this `apple/iOS10` issue or any pointer will be great help?

### Thanks in advance.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () {
    UIImagePickerController* vc;
    UIButton *shutterButton;
    int count;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)shutterButton_TouchUpInside:(UIButton*)button
{
    [vc takePicture];
    // [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.3 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer * _Nonnull timer) {
       // [vc takePicture];



    ///}];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
    NSLog(@"Took picture %d", count++);
    NSString *string1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Taken %d", count];
    [shutterButton setTitle:string1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [vc takePicture];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0f];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)ButtonToPush:(id)sender {
    UIButton *shutter = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    shutterButton =shutter;

    vc = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [[vc view] setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [vc setMediaTypes:@[@"public.image"]];
    [vc setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [vc setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear];
    [vc setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    [vc setCameraFlashMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff];
    [vc setAllowsEditing:NO];
    [vc setShowsCameraControls:NO];

    [shutter setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    [shutter setTitle:@"Take" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shutter addTarget:self action:@selector(shutterButton_TouchUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [vc setCameraOverlayView:shutter];
    [vc setDelegate:self];

    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

---

Logs from iPad Air2|iOS 10.1
App crashed when it took around 560 photos.

```
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 556
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 558
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 558
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=561, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12003ee00] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x120866200] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 557
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 559
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 559
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:51 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VoiceTrigger)[361] <Info>: ::: heartbeat: 4731904 score: -10.930287
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=562, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x120866200] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12003ee00] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 558
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 560
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 560
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=563, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12003ee00] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x120866200] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 559
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: localObjectDiedNotification: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 561
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 561
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: Removing listener ID: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: Cleaning up session(s) for client ID: <private> because it died
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 UserEventAgent(MemoryMonitor)[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 apsd(PersistentConnection)[368] <Notice>: 2016-11-01 13:33:52 +1100 apsd[368]: peer(830) received XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INVALID
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 ReportCrash[902] <Notice>: Launched ReportCrash to service - <private>
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[902] <Info>: scanned 28 logs with 1 types and 3 unknowns (sentinel is <private>)
Nov  1 13:33:52 HAIR2 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[902] <Notice>: Report of type '298(298)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 apsd(Security)[368] <Notice>: got event: Connection interrupted
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Notice>: Client /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework disconnected
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Info>: CLGyroBiasEstimator unknown client instance <private>
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Info>: CLGyroBiasEstimator,SPUEnabled,<private>,BuildingGYTT,<private>,NumClients,<private>
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 UserEventAgent(MemoryMonitor)[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=564, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[902] <Notice>: Report of type '298(298)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x121087200] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12003ee00] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 560
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 callservicesd(PlugInKit)[895] <Error>: Communications error: <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x1a5193af0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
  "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x1a5193df0> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}>
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 562
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 562
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=565, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x120866200] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x121087200] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 561
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 563
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 563
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:53 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VoiceTrigger)[361] <Info>: ::: heartbeat: 4762624 score: -10.930287
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=566, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12108bc00] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x120866200] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSessionMgr- CMSession: 'AVSC FigPlayer - 894' mediaremoted(pid = 894) requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMRoutingMgr- CMSession: Session requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 562
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 UserEventAgent(MemoryMonitor)[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(MediaRemote)[54] <Notice>: MediaRemote server disconnected.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(MediaRemote)[54] <Notice>: Service client's connection was interrupted. Reregistering custom origins with the media remote service.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[902] <Notice>: Report of type '298(298)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 coreduetd(MediaRemote)[901] <Notice>: MediaRemote server disconnected.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 coreduetd(MediaRemote)[901] <Notice>: Service client's connection was interrupted. Reregistering custom origins with the media remote service.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 callservicesd(CallKit)[895] <Notice>: Connection invalidated for call controller host connection: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 callservicesd(CallKit)[895] <Notice>: Connection invalidated for call controller host connection: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 622: -> Incoming Request : actionID 1108, inClientPID 855(CameraTest), inBehavior 0, customVibeDataProvided 0, loop 0, loopPeriod 0.000000, inFlags 0, inClientCompletionToken 564
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 263: mAudioToken /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/photoShutter.caf, mInUseCount 564
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 203: Data was marked NON-purgeable for actionID: 1108; this: 0x11d86db70
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(VirtualAudio)[361] <Info>: 228: Client request to get virtual format ([ 32/48000/2; flags: 0x29; bpp: 4; fpp: 1; Bpf: 4 ]) on virtual audio stream 113.
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSystSounds- CMSession: Called for SSID 1108, returning flags 0
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 126: mSSID 1108, mShouldPlayAudio 0, mShouldVibe 0, mAudioVolume 0.322500, mVibeIntensity 1.000000, mNeedsFinishCall 0, mSynchronizedSystemSound 0, mInterruptCurrentSystemSounds 0
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Info>: 875: Both sound and vibe flags are false for actionID 1108
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: Delaying application idle timer by 300.000000 seconds
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSurface: uniqueID=567, error=(null)
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12003ee00] Created session
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(AppleJPEG)[855] <Notice>: [0x12108bc00] Releasing session
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest[855] <Notice>: Took picture 563
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CameraTest(CameraUI)[855] <Notice>: capturePhotoWithSettings: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(AudioToolbox)[361] <Notice>: 94: sid:0x169056, coreduetd(901), 'prim'
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 BTServer[360] <Notice>: Sending 'session detached' event for session "com.apple.coreduetd-901-7299"
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 CommCenter[76] <Notice>: #I CTServerConnection from pid 901 has closed (conn=0x101377fc0)
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSessionMgr- CMSession: 'AVSC FigPlayer - 901' coreduetd(pid = 901) requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Notice>: Client /System/Library/LocationBundles/TimeZone.bundle disconnected
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 UserEventAgent(MemoryMonitor)[22] <Notice>: jetsam: kernel termination snapshot being created
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMRoutingMgr- CMSession: Session requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Info>: CLGyroBiasEstimator unknown client instance <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: localObjectDiedNotification: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMSessionMgr- CMSession: 'sid:0x169056, coreduetd(901), 'prim'' coreduetd(pid = 901) requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 locationd[372] <Info>: CLGyroBiasEstimator,SPUEnabled,<private>,BuildingGYTT,<private>,NumClients,<private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: Removing listener ID: com.apple.coreduetd
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 mediaserverd(CoreMedia)[361] <Notice>: -CMRoutingMgr- CMSession: Session requesting to set the discovery mode to DiscoveryMode_None
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 identityservicesd[373] <Notice>: Cleaning up session(s) for client ID: com.apple.coreduetd because it died
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 ReportCrash(CrashReporterSupport)[902] <Notice>: Report of type '298(298)' not saved because the limit of 25 logs has been reached
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 callservicesd(CallKit)[895] <Notice>: Connection invalidated for call controller host connection: <private>
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(BatteryCenter)[54] <Notice>: Power sources changed
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(BatteryCenter)[54] <Notice>: Query power sources
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 symptomsd(SymptomEvaluator)[374] <Notice>: 0x13ff095d0 for pid: 901, client event: 0
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(BatteryCenter)[54] <Notice>: Got a list of 1 sources
Nov  1 13:33:54 HAIR2 SpringBoard(BatteryCenter)[54] <Notice>: Found 1 power sources
```

Comment: please copy the relevant code directly in the question, no one wants to sift through your whole project

Comment: thanks for the advice, code pasted.

Comment: if you are able to reproduce the issue post crash log

Comment: No crash log recorded for some reason. but i have posted device logs.